# How can I create tabs apps?

Tags: tabs

I want to do when menu item is clicked, without refreshing the page and opening new tabs to see the contents of the page
It should close when I click X

What do I have to learn?
How do I search?

Thank you.

E.g: Like: [image: 1]]

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need to create it from scratch, Google is full of these code
>   snippets!

**Check this:**
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/panels-with-nav-tabs

And if you wanna learn it, just start with Html, CSS, JavaScript(jQuery)

**Check this:** 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nWrIBB_bMA&ytbChannel=LearnCode.academy

***Good luck!***

Comment: Thanks your comment. I need remote url tabs not one page tabs :)
Like this : https://youtu.be/gCfZjpIg52Q?t=6

Comment: Okay I don't get what you need exactly but I think if you have some experience in JavaScript, you only need to learn Angularjs or jQuery, depends on your needs! And always you can find code snippets to save your time!